# Where to find reference for the old angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am new to angular 4. The thing is when i try to use Angular Material in my project, I can only find the docs for the latest version:
[`MatSelect` api](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api)

They have changed the syntax to `mat` selectors.

For example:

```ts
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{ food.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Whereas, I'm doing a project which uses Angular 4 and an older version of Angular Material, which uses `md` selectors:

```ts
import {MdSelectModule} from '@angular/material';
```

The selectors for Angular Material are `md`.

Is there some form of reference for older versions?

Comment: The question is not dumb, but you are asking for help finding an off-site resource, which is off topic on SO.

Comment: What's your Angular Material version? Why can't you upgrade to Angular 5?

Comment: @Edric Well the thing is the existing code uses the old Angular Material ( which is 'md' ), if i want to upgrade i have to manually change every tag and module name to 'mat'. Or is there an another efficient way i dont know

Comment: according to the package.json file , the project use @angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.10"

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** Try not to ask off-topic questions here, as @R.Richards stated in the comments.

---

Anyways,

Follow these steps to get the docs for your Angular Material version.

1. Go to the [Github repo](https://github.com/angular/material2) and switch tags to the version you want.

   Use the button which is labelled <kbd>Branch: master</kbd> and click on it. You should see something like this:

   [image: Switch branch/tag button]

   You can use the input to search for the tag that you want.
2. Next, find the document you need which is labelled `*.md` (where the asterisk here is the library that you want to find).

   ---

   **TIP:** Use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>T</kbd> to open up "File Finder" where you can easily search for the file that you need. In this case, search for `select`.

   ### [image: File Finder]

Click on the docs that you need (probably `select.md` in this case). You should see the docs which are for that version.

Comment: Thanks for the github doc, however , in the github doc , it just stated the syntax for the tag used in html . In does not tell us which module to import to the app.module.ts file

Comment: Can you link the file?

Comment: For example , i am searching for cards component using https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2.0.0-beta.10/src/lib/card/card.md . It does not tell us to import {MdCardModule} from angular/material to the app.module.ts file

Comment: @NgocTuanLam API is generated automatically for every release. You can try viewing the source files.